# EF does not see manualy created migrations which came from merge

Tags: git, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I and my colleague are working on the same project, a small libruary that use EF 6 Code First aproach. To maintain database up to date we are using migrations. Yesterday I've merged my colleague's branch. That branch inculdes two new migrations which was created by `Add-Migration [MigrationName]` command.
Now when I try to run `Update-Database` command I am getting an error

```
Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.
```

I tried to re-run `Add-Migration` command to see what's "new" in model. EF created one giant migration for all changes that was made in my colleague's migrations. It looks like EF does not see migrations that came from merge

Comment: You need to get the migrationnames of your colleague and do `Add-Migration [MigrationName1]` then 2nd one to just update the metadata i believe

Comment: Thanks for advice. I've tried this approach.  For example I've got **AddContractTables** migration from my colleague and run `Add-Migration AddContractTables` just like you've adviced. EF have created new migration with name **AddContractTables1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found detailed answer for this problem here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn481501.aspx